# How do I check if the file the Scanner class in java is reading is complete?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Im using the scanner class to read a file for input and i'm using a try catch to check if the file is empty. However, if the input does not lead to the completion of the program, the code breaks. What I need is to check every line in the text file to see if it does not work, not only check if the file is empty

```
try {
                        in = new Scanner(new File(".\\Test\\data.txt"));
                        
                        

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        System.out.println("The text file is empty");
                        in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    }
```

This is the code that I have. Any suggestion/ critique is welcome

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` does *not* mean 'the text file is empty'. It means it doesn't exist or you can't access it. See the Javadoc. Don't guess.

Comment: @Dan I voted to undelete your correct answer.